# Synchronous SMPS Enabling with Charged Output

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

When using standard slow-start circuits that slew the 'comp' net for topologies like synchronous buck and boost converters, there can be reverse current events if the supply attempts to enable when the output caps are already charged up.

To work from an explicit example, say we are dealing with a boost converter that was previously regulating output voltage, then was disabled by driving both switches LOW, but is then re-enabled in quick succession prior to output caps discharging.  As comp starts to slew, the converter naturally moves through a low-duty cycle region and the high-side switch is ON for a large portion of the time.  Energy is sent back to the input bus as negative current builds up in the boost inductor.  Depending on details like how much energy was in the output caps, the slow start time, the boost inductor inductance value, etc., this pulse of energy can overstress components.

I have been attempting to understand standard ways of addressing this, but can't find any example of PWM controllers tackling it head-on.  I anticipate a few response:

- Controllers that don't allow forced CCM would prevent the negative current build up
- Usually the amount of energy stored in the output is low enough to not make this transient condition a problem (I've come accross this enough times now to be skeptical of this)
- You can implement a latch circuit that prevents the converter from re-enabling until the output falls back to the input voltage in the case of a boost.  (This is how I've addressed it previously but it feels clunky)

What is standard practice to address this?  It seems like a SMPS should handle the situation gracefully when someone rapidly attempts to enable and disable it.  If only output voltage could be fed forward to comp at some way during startup then it would have a more natural transition.

Comment: You can use diode or back-to-back mosfet to prevent reverse current flow. Also a quick discharge of output cap after power-off is a possible solution.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Do you see an issue with putting an ideal diode controller + FET between the buck output inductor and output capacitor bank to simplify the control here?